# Run process from Python service and keep it alive after service restart

Tags: python, linux

I created a Linux service using Python. The service can run/kill external processes using `Popen`.
But there is a small problem: after a service restart runned processes died.

## A couple of samples

- `pyservice.service` (Unit-file):

  ```sh
  [Service]
  ExecStart=/opt/pyservice/service.py
  ```
- `service.py`:

  ```sh
  ...
  subprocess.Popen('server.sh')
  ...
  ```
- `server.sh`:

  ```sh
  /usr/bin/java -server -jar ./Application.jar &
  ```

## What happens?

I run several instances of `server.sh` using `pyservice`.
`ps -aef --forest` shows me

```sh
python3.6 /opt/pyservice/service.py
\_ [server.sh] <defunct>
/usr/bin/java -server -jar ./Application.jar 
/usr/bin/java -server -jar ./Application.jar
```

If I kill `service.py`, my `Application.jar` will be killed too.

## What I expect?

After `service.py` kill or `pyservice` restart `server.sh` will running.

## What have I already tried?

Different combinations of `os.system`, `subprocess.Popen`, `nohup`, `&`, and their arguments.

What I'm doing wrong?